# 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found

Tags: react-native, xcode

Apos criar um projeto React Native pelo comando "react-native init project" e executar o cmd "react-native run-ios" para rodar o projeto obtive este erro "'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found" no MacOS. tenho o Xcode 10.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez seja a falha do comando 'pod install' no momento do react-native init.

> Solução:
>
> 1. Instalar o Cocoa Pods
>      `sudo gem install cocoapods`
> 2. Na sua Pasta do projeto `cd ios && pod install`
> 3. Por fim exluir a pasta `ios/build` e compilar novamente